# Unable to verify the first certificate - Postman

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have just started with Sitecore Commerce (10.1 with Sitecore 10.1) and Postman. When I try to bootstrap, it gives the error:

> Unable to verify the first certificate

I was able to get the token and the SSL is also turned off.

[image]

Comment: I think you can ignore that warning message, just check if urls, variables and environment are setup correctly in postman, by clicking on EYE icon

Comment: @qwerty did you ever get a resolution to this problem? I am seeing the exact same thing.