# Sitecore Identity Server Unhandled exception: "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified

Tags: sitecore-commerce, identity-server

I'm trying to run the PostMan GetToken method for Sitecore Commerce, which results in the error in PostMan [Unable to verify the first certificate - Postman](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-postman). Digging into the Sitecore Identity Server logs I am getting the following

```
12:13:43  Unhandled exception: "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.

at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)    
at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)    
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()    
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)    
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()    
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_HasPrivateKey()  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.HasPrivateKey(SecurityKey key)    
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)    
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)    
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)    
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)    
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)    
at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(JwtSecurityToken jwt)    
at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.<CreateTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.<CreateSecurityTokenAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)    at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<CreateAccessTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessTokenRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessTokenRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()"
```

I believe this is related to some sort of certificate error. I recently recreated the certificates due to the originals having expired, but I notice that my new certificate assigned to the Identity Server site in IIS does not reference the DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert. Is this the cause of my problem and is there a powershell command I can run to regenerate the certificate referencing the Sitecore Root cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem here was in my creation of the certificate.

I used something like this to create the certificate (BAD):

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -DnsName "localhost" -FriendlyName "Sitecore Commerce Services" -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment,DigitalSignature
```

I fixed the problem with the following certificate creation script (GOOD):

```
$selfSignedRootCA = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost" -FriendlyName "MattD Sitecore Commerce Services" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyUsage CertSign,CRLSign,DigitalSignature -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048 -KeyUsageProperty All -KeyAlgorithm 'RSA' -HashAlgorithm 'SHA256' -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'
$CertPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "b" -Force -AsPlainText
$selfSignedRootCA | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\certificates\SitecoreLocalhost20210719.pfx -Password $CertPassword
```

Please remember the following as well:

1. Select the new certificate in MMC and click "All Tasks > Manage Private Keys..." then set permission for IIS_IUSRS user account
2. Copy and paste the certificate into the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities
3. Paste the thumbprint of the certificate (ensure upper case) into \wwwroot\appsettings.json
4. Select the certificate for the IdentityServer website in IIS (under Bindings...)